# CSS font-face files not found

Tags: css, font-face

I'm trying to add fontello to my site.

Im calling the font via the instructions with it and have used it before easily. However it just doesn't seem to be working.

Here is my CSS:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'fontello';
  src: url('fonts/fontello.eot?54081114');
  src: url('fonts/fontello.eot?54081114#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('fonts/fontello.woff?54081114') format('woff'),
       url('fonts/fontello.ttf?54081114') format('truetype'),
       url('fonts/fontello.svg?54081114#fontello') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: I assume you are using `font-family: 'metaplus_bold_romanregular';` when you make your declarations.

Comment: Yep that is what I am using

Comment: Have you tried something simipler, like `font-family: 'MetaPlusBoldRoman';` in your font-face/family declarations? Wondering if the underscore could be a problem.

Comment: Just tried that, hasnt made a difference

Comment: According to your url paths, you are placing your fonts in the root of your css directory. Is that correct? Did you change the filenames?

Comment: yes I tried to simplify where the fonts had to go so I put them in the same directory as my css. I havent changed the name files.

Comment: @probablybest I think you should try to remove "?54081114..." from all the fonts.

Comment: From the link in your example, it is because the fonts are coming from a different domain. Hit "F12" you see this error in the console: Font from origin 'http://www.meganhutchinson.co.uk' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://megan.digital' is therefore not allowed access.